# Assigned material only shows up in Edit mode?

Tags: texturing, materials, edit-mode, object-mode

quick question. I've assigned a material to the rim of the windows in the picture in Edit mode, but in Object mode they are overwritten. Why is this happening and how could I prevent this?

Window rim in Edit mode with material correctly displayed:
[image: Window rim in Edit mode with material correctly displayed]

Window rim in Object mode where the material is overwritten by the brick material:
[image: Window rim in Object mode where the material is overwritten by the brick material]

Answer (score 0):

Your window rim material needs to be separate (and not the brick material).  Try putting a new material on the window rim and clear the UV mapped picture from it.
That's my best guess. A blend file would help reproduce.